# Reading from private effective user settings

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

When i click on button where this method is implemented then this type of error is occur. What does that mean? (IN APP PURCHASE)

```
System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/apple/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1F8BF693-81E9-49A0-890A-1FE1E766509D/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2016-12-01 19:09:25.624659 DishantInAppPurchase[7450:317095] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
```

Comment: did you add -in-app purchase permission to info.plist ?

Comment: What permissions? Can you please write the code of permission.